# Fortigate 200A firewall CPU high resource usage

Tags: networking, firewall

This morning I'm receiving complaints from several end users that saying their whole department network are slow and have intermittent.

Therefore I've checked our firewall to see whether if something goes wrong with the device.From my observation in the FortiGate dashboard status, the CPU resources is very high (99 percent).
My first assumption is to clear the log since in the alert log the Fortigate log mention that it is already 90% full.Based on my understanding,the log can be cleared by restarting the firewall.

After restarting the firewall the network seems okay again but then after several minutes it went up again.The condition still persist until now.

Can someone show me where else I can check to fix this issue? I've really appreciate any help that I can get here.Thanks.

Edit:

diag sys top command

[image]

Comment: Any unusual network activity at the machines behind the firewall? Install e.g. [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) on one machine and monitor the network when it goes "slow". Unfortunately, you don't have a clean baseline to compare. Download the logs from the firewall and analyze them. Maybe you are being the subject of some kind of attack, or a worm went wild in your network (update and run all antivirus and other malware deletion software at hand, including [clamav](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/about/win32)).

Comment: so far from my end, nothing unusual network activity behind the firewall.but there is possibility for the attack as you have mention.
I've also tried to disable some of the service in order to reduce the CPU resources but I'm unable to stop the service (for example: ips,antivirus, etc..).It showing me this error 'CFG_CMDBAPI_ERR'

Comment: @TildalWave I've already put the output for `#diag sys top` command above.I want to test `#diag test app ipsmonitor 99`  command but there are many user currently using the internet.So I cannot restart the firewall.

Comment: I've run the command as mention several times for a long time on each diagnostics.The output are almost similar with the one post above.Mysteriously the CPU resources right now showing 40 - 70 % output although I didn't do anything else towards the firewall.
Maybe there are something else are affecting our firewall?btw, can you explain to me each column which represent the output above.Cause I'm not sure which part should I look at.

Comment: hm..Ok.Anyway there are some explanation that I think which we can refer for the command description : [here](http://zecure.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/understand-the-diagnose-sys-top-command-in-fortigate/)

Answer (score 1):

I've already resolved this issues.For the sake to help others who might facing the same problem, I'm writing this down.

When tracing back to our firewall log, I've found out that there are several log indicating VPN SSL error.
After comparing the log with the time of the occurrence of network intermittent as well as the high CPU percentage resources,I've conclude that the VPN service for this firewall is the root for all these problem.

Then after disabling the VPN service,the network went back normal until today.Something within the VPN service is eating up  the CPU resources greedily. 
Regardless,we already plan to buy a new Fortinate firewall model to accommodate the increasing number of users in our workplace.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the letter S for the highest CPU and you can restart that application by killing the PID - Process ID diag sys kill 11 903  (9 or 11 will kill the PID and restart it 9 is safer 11 keeps no track of you killing it in logs so try 9 first then 11). usually the CPU will go back down. if it happens frequently then i would suggest installing a new Forti IOS image on the box no need to replace the box since these are software and not hardware related. for the most part.

---

CLI# diagnose sys top

Run Time: 13 days, 13 hours and 58 minutes
0U, 0S, 98I; 123T, 25F, 32KF
newcli 903 R 0.5 5.5
sshd 901 S 0.5 4.0

Where the codes displayed on the second output line mean the following:

- U is % of user space applications using CPU. In the example, 0U means 0% of the user space applications are using CPU.
- S is % of system processes (or kernel processes) using CPU. In the example, 0S means 0% of the system processes are using the CPU.
- I is % of idle CPU. In the example, 98I means the CPU is 98% idle.
- T is the total FortiOS system memory in Mb. In the example, 123T means there are 123 Mb of system memory.
- F is free memory in Mb. In the example, 25F means there is 25 Mb of free memory.
- KF is the total shared memory pages used. In the example, 32KF means the system is using 32 shared memory pages.

Each additional line of the command output displays information for each of the processes running on the FortiGate unit. For example, the third line of the output is:

newcli 903 R 0.5 5.5

Where:

- newcli is the process name. Other process names can include ipsengine, sshd, cmdbsrv, httpsd, scanunitd, and miglogd.
- 903 is the process ID. The process ID can be any number.
- R is the state that the process is running in. The process state can be:
  o R running.
  o S sleep.
  o Z zombie.
  o D disk sleep.
- 0.5 is the amount of CPU that the process is using. CPU usage can range from 0.0 for a process that is sleeping to higher values for a process that is taking a lot of CPU time.
- 5.5 is the amount of memory that the process is using. Memory usage can range from 0.1 to 5.5 and higher.

Interactive diagnose sys top commands

You can enter the following single-key commands when diagnose sys top is running.

- Press q to quit.
- Press c to sort the processes by the amount of CPU that the processes are using.
- Press m to sort the processes by the amount of memory that the processes are using.

Stopping running processes

You can use the following command to stop running processes:

diagnose sys kill

Where:

- signal can be any number but 11 is preferred because this signal sends output to the crashlog which can be used by Fortinet Support to troubleshoot problems.
- process id is the process ID listed by the diagnose sys top command.

For example, to stop the process with process ID 903, enter the following command:

diagnose sys kill 11 903